# drupalSettings values lost when accessed from a named function

Tags: javascript

I have a custom module and in it's .module file I add a value to Drupal settings:

```
  $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['my module']['color_body'] = '#dd0000';
```

I have a named js function and try to access the value:

```
function loadcal() {
  var backgroundColor = drupalSettings.mymodule.color_body;
}
```

I receive the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'my module')
at Object.attach (loadcal.js?rb7yo3:52:37)
```

All of the working examples of using drupalSettings seem to be with anonymous functions:

```
(function ($) {}
```

I can refactor to do this as a DOMready function, but would prefer this function to be callable. I have tried:

```
(function loadcal($) {}
```

but that leaves loadcal() not being found when it is called.

**UPDATE**

I decided I could do without the function being named. I could pass what I needed at the start and not have to make subsequent calls. Here is the code involved:

**mymodule.libraries**

```
mymodule.calendar:
  css:
    component:
      css/calendar.css: {}
  js:
    js/loadcal.js: { weight: -18 }
  dependencies:
    - core/Drupal
    - core/jQuery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

**mymodule.module**

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('mymodule.settings');
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mymodule.calendar';
  $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['mymodule']['color_body'] = '#dd0000';
}
```

**loadcal.js**

```
(function (Drupal, drupalSettings, once) {
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        dayCellDidMount: ({date, el}) => {
          el.style.backgroundColor = drupalSettings.mymodule.color_body;
        }
      }
   }
)}
```

The console error is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'color_body')

though when checking drupalSettings, and settings under Closure (attach), or Closure.drupalSettings, mymodule isn't there, though  it shows up under Drupal.behaviors.

Comment: Why the space in `'my module'`?

Comment: The exception message doesn't match the shown code. With `drupalSettings.mymodule`, it should not complain about reading the *my module* property of `undefined`.

Comment: You can either use `(function ($) { /* code */ })(jQuery)` or `(function loadcal($) { /* code */ })(jQuery)`. The latter would be helpful if that function calls itself (which doesn't usually happen with Drupal behaviors).

Comment: This will probably come down to how you're including the JS in the page or how/when you're invoking `loadcal()`

Comment: @Clive Yes, that's true. We need to see more code, but so far this seems a plain JavaScript question.

Comment: `$variables` needs to be `&$variables` in the preprocess function declaration

Comment: Thank you! I’ll fix that and try as soon as I stop banging my head on the desk :)

Comment: Yup. Works. Please add it as an answer.